# Draggable div in scrolling container bounces when reaching bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm putting together a custom UI control in pure JS which simulates a schedule of events. One event is represented by a draggable div.

Here are the most relevant JS functions:

```
function onDrag(event)
{
    console.log("**** DRAG ****");

    if (dragging)
    {
        console.log("dragging = " + dragging);

        //event.preventDefault();

        currentY = event.clientY - initialY;

        // Check whether we need to scroll up or down

        //handleScroll();

        // Limit dragging to size of background container

        if(currentY < 0)
        {
            currentY = 0;
        }
        else if(currentY > background_height - draggable.offsetHeight)
        {
            currentY = background_height - draggable.offsetHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            currentY = currentY;
        }

        yOffset = currentY;

        moveIt(currentY);
    }
}

function moveIt(yPos)
{
    console.log("moveIt : yPos = " + yPos);

    draggable.style.transform = "translate3d( 0px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcadke15/)

Everything basically works, but not surprisingly, it doesn't work as cleanly as I had hoped.

When dragging to the bottom of the parent container, the container should auto scroll. In practice, the draggable div follows the mouse until I drag below the container, at which point, the draggable bounces back about 300px upwards and plants itself towards the middle of the container (often partly or completely out of the viewport).

What I want is for the draggable to just park itself at the edge of the parent container, even if I try to drag it 1000px away. If I mouse very slowly, the container scrolls properly and the draggable stops on the edge, but if I'm sloppy and drag past the edge (as I anticipate most users will do), I get the bounce.

Sample console log depicting the bounce:

```
**** DRAG ****
dragging = true
moveIt : yPos = 712
**** DRAG LEAVE ****
**** DRAG ****
dragging = true
moveIt : yPos = 713
**** DRAG ****
dragging = true
moveIt : yPos = 713
**** DRAG ****
dragging = true
moveIt : yPos = 415
```

I can switch from HTML5 drag and drop and use a MouseEvent driven style, simply by commenting out the drag and drop listeners and substituting mouse events to avoid this bouncing effect. The fact that things work the way I want with mouse events suggests to me that I'm running into something undocumented with HTML5 DnD. I'm happy to switch to this mouse event driven approach, but then I have to implement scrolling manually and when I try that, the more I drag, the further the draggable moves from the mouse pointer. You can edit the fiddle, commenting out the DnD listeners

I'm happy to have a solution either the DnD or mouse event approaches, but mainly, I want to know what's causing these odd behaviors. Is there something wrong with the way I've structured the page? Is the CSS messed up? Is there some undocumented (but perhaps expected) behavior causing these problems?

Comment: This seems like something out of my scope, but maybe because its losing its Y-position when you scroll while holding the object to the bottom? Can you log its position when the scroll is occurring, that might help out a little.

Comment: @GrandIQ Yeah, dumping values to console was the first thing I tried. I added a sample console log to the question, and you can see a 298px jump without me letting go of the mouse or letting the button up. The value doesn't seem like it's being lost -- it just changes. I suspect that this is a quirk that I just haven't read about.

Comment: I just noticed something that might help you (I hope). When you drag the item to the bottom of the initial drag screen, while holding it down, scroll down just a little. On chrome you can see a "Shadow" of what your dragging, the initial item that I dragged seems to stick to the bottom of the page, but as I descend (Scroll down) further, the shadow follows my cursor but not the actual item. It seems like the object is losing the cursors position as the scroll is occurring. Is the function depended on a specific scroll position to trigger?